# Bash Input Variables & Loop

Tags: bash, loops

My script

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo "[*] 1 - Create a gnome-terminal"
    echo "[*] 2 - Display Ifconfig"
    echo -n "Pick an Option > "
    read Input

    if [ "$Input" = "1" ]; then
        gnome-terminal
        sleep 3
    echo "[*] 1 - Create a gnome-terminal"
    echo "[*] 2 - Display Ifconfig"
    echo -n "Pick an Option > "
    read Input

    fi

    if [ "$Input" = "2" ]; then
        clear
        ifconfig
    echo "[*] 1 - Create a gnome-terminal"
    echo "[*] 2 - Display Ifconfig"
    echo -n "Pick an Option > "
    read Input

    fi

done
```

Doesn't reuse the Input variable, say if you want to run the ifconfig option multiple times in a row. It rechecks the first variable string to see if it matches "1", and when it doesn't it echoes back the list of options. Any ideas on how to make any input variable accessible regardless of when it is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `select` instead of rolling your own menu:

```
choices=(
    "Create a gnome-terminal" 
    "Display Ifconfig"
)
PS3="Pick an Option > "
select action in "${choices[@]}"; do 
    case $action in 
        "${choices[0]}") gnome-terminal; sleep 3;; 
        "${choices[1]}") clear; ifconfig;; 
        *) echo invalid selection ;; 
    esac
done
```

`select` gives you an infinite loop by default. If you want to break out of it, put a `break` statement into the `case` branch.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're writing out the menu twice on each iteration. Stop doing that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    echo "[*] 1 - Create a gnome-terminal"
    echo "[*] 2 - Display Ifconfig"
    echo -n "Pick an Option > "
    read Input

    if [ "$Input" = "1" ]; then
        gnome-terminal
        sleep 3
    fi

    if [ "$Input" = "2" ]; then
        clear
        ifconfig
    fi
done
```

Comment: Omfg I feel dumb now. Thank you for pointing that out. I was trying to get that list after every command from the input was completed.. and that certainly solved it.

Comment: anyway, you case for this